# Iterate through a json with hierarchical children and add a key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, tree

I want to convert the existing data to other. Please find below the existing code and the expected code.

Existing:

{
    "title": "title1",
    "child": [
        {
        "title": "Header",
        "child": 
        [
            {
            "title": "test",
            "child": 
            [
                           {
                 "title": "testchild",

```
            },
           {
              "title": "Descriptionchild",
            }
             ]

            },
            {
                "title": "Description",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Expected:

{
    "title": "title1",
    "customId": "title1-xx"
    "child": [
        {
            "title": "Header",
            "customId": "Header1-xx",
            "child": 
            [
                {
                    "title": "test",
                    "customId": "test1-xx",
                    "child": 
                        [
                            {
                                "title": "testchild",
                                "customId": "testchild1-xx"

```
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Descriptionchild",
                            "customId": "Descriptionchild1-xx"
                        }
                    ]

            },
            {
                "title": "Description",
                "customId": "Description1-xx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: where do you get the missing values from? please add your try.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a function that takes an array and recursively add this attribute:

```
// input must be array
function recursivelyAddCustomId(input) {
  // if input is not empty i.e. child is not empty
  if (input != null) {
    // for each child object in array
    for (let obj of input) {
      // set custom id
      if (obj.title != null) {
        obj.customId = obj.title + '-xx';
      }
      // recurse (doesn't matter if child exists)
      recursivelyAddCustomId(obj.child);
    }
  }
}
// put input as array
recursivelyAddCustomId([input]);
console.log(input);
```

Note that the input for this function must be an array so the first object must be converted to an array first.

Please let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.

**Note:** Comments are made in code block